# Reactjs function not being called

Tags: reactjs

I'm implementing the Facebook SDK on my react project, however, I am new to React and I still don't grasp some concepts. I'm calling `handleFBLogin` when a user clicks on a button. This function then calls `checkLoginState` to continue my code's logic. I've already bound `checkLoginState` in the constructor using:

`this.CheckLoginState = this.checkLoginState.bind(this);`

I call this function on `handleFBLogin`, but checkLoginState doesn't seem to be called. I can see the `yes` on my console:

```
handleFBLogin() {
    console.log("yes")
    this.checkLoginState;
}
```

Here's the `checkLoginState` function:

```
checkLoginState(){
    console.log("checloginstate")
    window.FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      this.statusChangeCallback(response);
    }.bind(this));

}
```

Why isn't it being called?

Comment: "yes" is being logged ?

Comment: Yeah, sorry I forgot to mention it.

Comment: this.checkLoginState()

Comment: Where are you invoking the method ?

Comment: **this.checkLoginState()** if u use bind this function this change is enough to call

Comment: You forgot the parenthesis for `this.checkLoginState()` in the `handleFBLogin()` method.

Comment: When I try `this.checkLoginState()` it errors out: TypeError: this.checkLoginState is not a function when clicking on the button.

Comment: In your binding you have "Check" with capital C and then with lower case. Only use one as it is case sensitive.

Comment: check this once https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-knjwjl

Comment: @Chris Still tells me it's not a function..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible you think to call the function without using parentheses as you do in the event like `onClick={this.yourMethod}`. It works because the react will handle it internally.

But calling a function from a method to another, you need to call the function using parentheses:

```
this.checkLoginState()
```

But wait! `this` will be undefined here if have not bind `this`. So, bind this inside your constructor:

```
this.handleFBLogin = this.handleFBLogin.bind(this)
```

---

Alternatively, you may use public class method:

```
handleFBLogin = () => {
  this.checkLoginState()
```

Comment: Unfortuantely, it gives me a `TypeError: this.checkLoginState is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

I think it is type error. You forgot to add '()' for calling a function.

```
handleFBLogin() {
    console.log("yes")
    this.checkLoginState();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

inside `handleFBLogin()` try `() => this.checkLoginState();` . You need the parenthesis to invoke the method.